# Using ngFor in Angular2, how can I do an "inner" ngFor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

Question might be hard to understand but my problem is simple:

- I want to display a list of contacts.
- I'm displaying them as cards using bootstrap
- I want each row to show 4 cards

HTML structure:

```
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <!-- Here I want to loop 4 of the contacts before rendering a new row -->
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <contact-card [contact]="contact"></contact-card>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or more simplified, I want to do achieve this:
[image]

Is there a way to do an "inner" ngFor in `col-md-3` div, which stops after rendering 4 contacts?

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557781/angular-2-show-hide-wrap-tag-in-ngfor-over-even-odd-items/42558062#42558062

Comment: You could add `let i = index` to your `*ngFor` and then you will have the index of the current card on `i` variable.

Comment: you want all 4 contacts same or different in a row?

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42268913/6806381 - The solution was to first split the array into sub arrays, then iterate with nested `*ngFor`'s

Answer (score 0):

You could create two components: one to display a single card, and second - to display a row of cards.

More code overall, but each component is simpler, more cohesive and reusable; the two components are decoupled.

At last, you could process all the cards' data as stream and form batches of required amount of cards to fill rows.